# Why does not work pipe orderby?

Tags: angular

Call like this:

```
<span *ngFor="let lang of languages | orderBy:def">{{lang.code}}</span>
```

Where `def` from `lang.def` and can be `true/false`

Pipe code is availabel by [link](http://www.allenhashkey.com/web-development/angular2/angular-2-order-by-pipe/):
When I use this pipe it does not filter by `def` value(boolean)

Comment: Question can be closed. I solved

Comment: If you think your solution can help others, I invite you to answer to your own question and mark it as solved. Otherwise, if you prefer to close the question, you can delete it on your own. May the following link could help you : [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/366499)

Comment: Okay, I will share soon own solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular no longer supports orderBy. https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe
You will have to create your own function to sort through your data.